# Simulate swipe in ionic with protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, protractor

I'm on a ionic app. I use the list component with the can-swipe="listCanSwipe" attribute :
http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionList/

I wish to test the correct working of the button which is revealed this way, but i can't simulate the swipe with Protractor.

Many post, here and elsewhere, suggest to do something like this :

```
    browser.actions()
        .mouseDown(myItem)
        .mouseMove({x: -200, y: 0})
        .mouseUp()
        .perform()
```

I try this, only added ".then(browser.pause())" to  check the result.

But it doesn't work. I log in the browser console the mouse down, mouse move and mouse up event on the container, and i get something like this :

```
  move : x450 y200      
  down : x450 y200
  move : x250 y200
  up : x250 y200
```

Coordinates are exactly what i need, but the list item doesn't move and the button doesn't appear. I tought that it can due to a too quick gesture, so i tried an another solution :

```
    browser.actions()
        .mouseDown(myItem)
        .perform();

    for(var i = 0; i < 200; i++){
        browser.actions()
        .mouseMove({x: -1, y: 0})
        .perform();
        browser.sleep(5);
    }

    browser.actions()
        .mouseUp()
        .perform()
        .then(browser.pause());
```

And i get something like :

```
move : x450 y200
down : x450 y200
move : x449 y200
move : x448 y200
...
move : x251 y200
move : x250 y200
up : x250 y200
```

And it doesn't work either : i briefly see the active state (grey background), then nothing during one second, then the browser pause. It look like the mouse move doesn't perform with the button down.

Does anybody have a tip for me ?
Thank you in advance.